# Azure VM SQL Server Web edition and SSRS

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I need to setup SSRS on an Azure VM to use an Azure Database as the data source. Can I use SQL Server Web edition on the VM or do I need standard/enterprise edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your description, NO.

The answer depends. If you require remote and non-SQL data source support then NO. If you only need to access the local Web Edition SQL Server then YES.

You will find that the Web Edition is very limited in its support and is intended for local SQL Server support.

This link provides a table of supported configurations.

[Reporting Services Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016)

Comment: OK great. Thanks for the info